# Couldn't navigate through directories using bash script

Tags: bash, bashrc, bash-history

Through script I am not able to change into directories and list the files.
`cd` is not working.

Here is my script

```
#!/bin/bash

export HOME=/home/yesh

DIR_START=2
DIR_END=`wc -l < ${HOME}/conf/DirectoryList`

while [ ${DIR_START} -le ${DIR_END} ];
do
        DIR1=`cat /home/yesh/conf/DirectoryList | sed -ne ${DIR_START}p`
        echo "cd ${HOME}/${DIR1}"
        find . -type f > /home/yesh/Files_"$(date +%Y%d%m)".log
done
```

```
DirectoryList
/home/yesh/yesh.txt
/home/yesh/Yesh
/home/yesh/BACKUP
/home/yesh/venv3
/home/yesh/pythonfund
```

The above are the list of directories I need to navigate through in  `${HOME}/conf/DirectoryList`

Comment: It's really not at all clear to me what you expect this script to do

Comment: i need to navigate through the list of folders present in DirectoryList file to make a list of files present in them

Comment: Please explain that, and give us some detail, after clicking on https://askubuntu.com/posts/1054249/edit , Put your responses in the original post, instead of answering here, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the list of directories is not too large, I'd suggest avoiding the shell loop altogether and simply passing the list to `find` via an array:

```
mapfile -t dirs < "${HOME}/conf/DirectoryList"
find "${dirs[@]}" -type f > /home/yesh/Files_"$(date +%Y%d%m)".log
```

If you still want to use a shell loop instead, then

```
while read -r dir; do
  find "$dir" -type f
done < "${HOME}/conf/DirectoryList" > /home/yesh/Files_"$(date +%Y%d%m)".log
```

If the intent of your `cd` was to remove the leading path components from the output, then you can do that within `find` by replacing the default print by an explicit `-printf '%P\n'`